# How to properly get results from JPA JOIN request?

Tags: java, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa, left-join

I have two JPA entities:

```
@Entity
public class ClientEntity {
   ...
   @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY)
   private List<OrderEntity> orders;
}

@Entity
public class OrderEntity {
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   private ClientEntity client;
}
```

I'm making LEFT OUTER JOIN using JPA Specification API:

```
public static Specification<ClientEntity> allClientsOrders() {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        Join<ClientEntity, TestOrderEntity> join = root.join("orders", JoinType.LEFT);
        return cb.and();
    };
}
```

Now I need to get standard JOIN results: if a client has 3 orders in DB, I want him to be returned 3 times with another order each time. However, it returns me the client 3 times, but each time the client has all 3 orders.

As I see in logs, Java sends the first SQL query correctly, but then sends other ones to fill the client with orders as usual.

How can I prevent this and get the results as one client - one order pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to prevent Client from loading only some part of the relation.

But join operation is not needed for the purpose you described. Instead, search for Orders. You will get 3 Orders. Each Order has relation to a client, thus you will get what you need: 3 Order objects each combined with a Client.

If because of some reason you want that that your query returns combinations of these 2 type, consider following approach: Define a new bean/DTO that will represent a projection of fields of each combination of your 2 objects. Then use JPQL like following:

```
select new mypackage.MyJoinDto (
    c.id,
    c.firstName,
    c.lastName,
    ...
    o.productName,
    o.orderDate,
    ...
)
from ClientEntity c left outer join TestOrderEntity o
    on o.clientId = c.id
```

This MyJoinDto doesn't need any JPA annotations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the JOIN behavior, because I need clients w/o any orders to be added to the list as well. Based on your answer it seems the only option I have is to do not use Specification.

Comment: @OlegE: If you find the answer helpful, you can show this by voting up.